# Resolve seemingly circular imports in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to resolve what seems to be a circular imports issue in Flask, however, I'm struggling to understand this as I believe I'm using the same structure as in the [documentation](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/organizing.html) and with the same imports pattern as in the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

My structure looks much the same:

```
root/
    run.py
    config.py
    app/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        models.py
    env/
```

**`app/__init__.py`**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import * 
app = Flask(__ name __)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)  
from app import views, models
```

(The import views, models statement is the last line in `__init__.py`)

**`app/views.py`**

```
from app import app, db
from models import Entry, Category
from config import *
```

**`app/models.py`**

```
from app import db
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/paulmclear/Coding/projects/prodblog/app/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from app import views, models
ImportError: cannot import name views
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: (It is indeed a circular import issue).

Comment: You should probably avoid using `app` both as the name of a module (directory) and as a local variable name. And it's highly recommended that you would put all your import at the top of the file, before any other lines of code (except docstring and comments)

Comment: Thanks @spectras, thats what I thought - but what I'm struggling to understand is how the Flask Microblog over at miguelgrinberg.com doesn't result in the same error / issue?  In __init__.py he has from app import views, and in views he has from app import app

Comment: The final `import` line in `__init__.py` doesn't make sense to me. But I'm not familiar with Flask. Do you have a link to where you found that suggestion?

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid - Following [this pattern](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).  Yes, the "strange" things are to get around the markup in StackOverflow, which emboldens anything surrounded by '__' - the code itself is not like this

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes, it uses db.session

Comment: Did you try `from . import views, models` ?

Comment: Thanks @metmirr - that has fixed it!